# JS-Canvas: Redraw Shape On Window Resize

Tags: javascript, canvas

my app listens for resize events and adjusts the width and the height of my canvas:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  this.canvasWidth = innerWidth
  this.canvasHeight = innerHeight    
})
```

When I resize the window the canvas resizes perfectly, but the shape that I've drawn on the canvas disappears.

How can I keep the drawn object visible?

Answer (score 0):

suddenly it works, I just had to call it with a requestAnimationFrame-method.

```
const loop = () => {
  this.update()
  this.draw()
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}
loop()
```